# pass variable to window.location.replace for redirecting

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to redirect my page to another one after the function success,
but it is not reading my variable inside window.location.replace.

```
 var thenum = client.replace( /^\D+/g, '');
    $.ajax({
      url: '/signature_pad.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
        imageData: imagen,
        id: thenum,
      },

    })
        .done(function (msg) {
          // Image saved successfuly.
          window.location.replace('http://something.com/show.php?id=${ thenum }');
        })
        .fail(function (msg) {
          console.log("error: " + msg);
        });
```

is there any way to redirect my to [http://something.com/show.php?id=${](http://something.com/show.php?id=$%7B) num } where it has to pass the variable to the id

Comment: Have you defined `num` ?

Comment: in addition to issues noted in other comments/answers, to use the `${...}` syntax you need to surround the string in backticks, not quotes

Comment: Ofisora, Yes I already defined, actually it was thenum which I defined on the top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

need to change

```
window.location.replace('http://something.com/show.php?id=${ thenum }');
```

to

```
window.location.href = ('http://something.com/show.php?id=' + thenum);
```

Comment: No need for parenthesis

Answer (score 0):

`replace()` returns a new string, and requires 2 arguments, the search value and the replacement value. Also, it looks like you are trying to use a template literal. Those use ` instead of '.

If you want to redirect the page you need to use `window.location.href`:

```
window.location.href = "newURL";
```

Comment: I need to get only numbers, that's why I use replace(), it is working fine and passing only number, like:

    `var client = window.location.href;
    var thenum = client.replace( /^\D+/g, '');`

I tried to use 
`window.location.href = "newURL"; 
window.location.href = ('http://something.com/show.php?id=${thenum}');`

it is still redirecting to http://something.com/show.php?id=${thenum}

Comment: In this: 'http://something.com/show.php?id=${thenum}', the quotes need to be replaced with ` and you don't need parenthesis.

Comment: I tried it did not work,
`window.location.href = ('http://isomething.com/show.php?id=' + thenum);`
that one is worked

Comment: The other one will work if you replace the quotes with this symbol: ` It is called an acute, back quote, grave, grave accent, left quote, open quote, and a push. It should be on the top-left of your keyboard.